# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth making text too small/ trying to check font size

Tags: ios, swift, text, fonts, font-size

I am creating multiple buttons in my code, each one grabbing its text from separate arrays. I AM using the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` (That was the only thing I could find that would automatically resize the text, so it fits within the frame of the button). However, when some the text adjusts, it can get ridiculously small; it's definitely smaller than it needs to be. Is there any way you can make sure the text only sizes as much as it needs to?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    correctWord.text = correctAnswer[questionNumber]

    correctWord.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1 * self.view.frame.width / 4, 1.5 * self.view.frame.height / 22)

    correctWord.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2, 14.25 * self.view.bounds.height / 22)

    correctWord.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    correctWord.numberOfLines = 1

    correctWord.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE", size: 60)

    correctWord.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    correctWord.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    correctWord.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters

    correctWord.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1

    self.view.addSubview(correctWord)
```

I DID try a code that I saw while searching (found below). I created a function for the code to update the text size, and I called it before `self.view.addSubview(correctWord)`. But, the button never appears. And, is there a way you can check to see what the font size actually is? When I print `currentSize` to the logs to determine the font size, it always says "0". I am trying to determine which text's size is the smallest, so all of the buttons can be set to the same font size.

```
func adjustFontSizeToFitRect(rect : CGRect){

    if correctWord.text == nil{
        return
    }

    correctWord.frame = rect

    let maxFontSize: CGFloat = 100.0
    let minFontSize: CGFloat = 5.0

    var q = Int(maxFontSize)
    var p = Int(minFontSize)

    let constraintSize = CGSize(width: rect.width, height: CGFloat.max)

    while(p <= q){
         currentSize = (p + q) / 2

        correctWord.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE", size: CGFloat(currentSize))

        let textRect = correctWord.text!.boundingRectWithSize(constraintSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: nil, context: nil)


        let labelSize = textRect.size

        if labelSize.height < correctWord.frame.height && labelSize.height >= correctWord.frame.height-10 && labelSize.width < correctWord.frame.width && labelSize.width >= correctWord.frame.width-10 {
            break
        }else if labelSize.height > correctWord.frame.height || labelSize.width > correctWord.frame.width{
            q = currentSize - 1
        }else{
            p = currentSize + 1
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` results in the font being too small, don't set `minimumScaleFactor` to such a small value. Use something like `0.7` instead of `0.1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, maddy! I feel dumb for not realizing that.